# XML to CSV/Excel

Tags: python, xml, excel, csv, rss

I have an RSS formatted XML file - what I usually do is import that into excel using the PC developer tools. That fancy'ness creates a tree for me automatically and I simply drag and drop the root element onto the spreadsheet, hit refresh data and boom I have a CSV or excel file that I can do any number of things with that I could do with the raw RSS file.

I'd like to skip this step of going to excel on PC etc and use something like python to get the job done on my mac. Problem is I don't want to have to tell phyon the tree, elements etc I want it to figure it out and give me a CSV! -

Any guidance on how I might be able to accomplish this task?

Comment: https://github.com/knadh/xmlutils.py might be a good library to use

Comment: if u are planning to write the code then this link http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-xml-to-csv-using-python/ might help. You would need the names of all tags to write the script by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML2Json actually worked out OK

```
xml2json --input "/Users/me/Downloads/file.xml" --output "file_2.json
```

There's some formatting issues in terms of headers but I can clean that up.